# Automator/applescript to center desktop background (OSX 10.9 Mavericks)

Tags: image, macos, applescript, desktop, automator

I am using an automator workflow (Get specified URLs>Get Image URLs from Webpage>Download URLs>Set the Desktop Picture) to get a daily image from a website to set as my desktop background.

The image is a fixed 720px wide. When the automator workflow runs it sets the background image with the fitting options of "Fill Screen."

How can I set the fitting options to "Center" and set background color to "White"?

So far my best searching has lead me to something like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell current desktop
        get properties
    end tell
end tell
```

But I'm pretty new to Applescripts and Automator in general.